# Unknown ssh login error, hangs for unknown reason

Tags: ssh, remote-login

I'm trying to log into a VM instance using, but for some reason it's hanging at:

```
$ mforde@igsb:~$ ssh -vvv -l ubuntu -i ~/.ssh/mf-half.pem 172.16.215.255
OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config 
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 172.16.215.255 [172.16.215.255] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug3: Incorrect RSA1 identifier
debug3: Could not load "/home/mforde/.ssh/mf-half.pem" as a RSA1 public key
debug1: identity file /home/mforde/.ssh/mf-half.pem type -1
debug1: identity file /home/mforde/.ssh/mf-half.pem-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.6
```

The key worked fine until this weekend, and works fine with other VMs. Also the VM successfully responds to pings.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Not sure I'm seeing any problems with the log you've provided.  Seems to be just a normal key based authentication for ssh v2 and not v1.  Do you have any more log?  And can you access the machine at `172.16.215.255` to check it's sshd_config?

Comment: Yea, key is fine too. No more log. That's where it hangs, and it's a VM so there's no physical access.

Comment: It's really weird.

Comment: Yeah.  It's like the remote machine is there, but not running an ssh server.  I expect the next line of the log to tell you what is the "remote" ssh version and software, but if the log ends at the local information, it's like there is no ssh service on the VM... sorry, but I have to say "have you tried turning it off and on again?"  :-)  That will certainly restart the ssh service.

Comment: yea, that's the next step. however i have a scratch space mounted to the VM so I'm afraid of losing data. well it's not like i can get to the data anyway, so it's a wash. maybe i can make a copy of the volume.

Comment: Unless you have some other way to get into the VM (telnet or your VM console; e.g. "show" in virtualbox), I'm afraid you might be out of luck and you'll just have to sacrifice the data.

Answer (score 0):

Your VM IP address seems a little strange because it ending with 255 like a broadcast address. Are you using a /16 netmask?
Can you ping it?
Do you have any local console on that VM by the way?

Can you try to delete this VM RSA key from your trusted keys list on the local machine? Maybe it was changed and it's the reason why you can't login again.

Comment: If that was the problem, then the OP would not be able to connect at all. Note that for the past two decades, with CIDR, netmasks can be of any length. RFC 1918 reserves 172.16.0.0/12, but that space can be divided in any way desired.